# Matlab GUi How to come back to the command window when axes is refreshing

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I am writing a Matlab GUI and I need to show images in one axes. The images come from the camera. So I find when use preview to display the camera with one axes, I can go back to the command window. But when I use get the image with the getsnapshot() function and do some processing then use the other axes to display the processed images in real time, I find I can not go back to the command window. That maybe because the axes is refreshing all the time. So when I click the command window, the axes popup then disturb the command window. So anyone knows the solution. The following is my GUI panel.

[image: GUI panel. I preview the camera with video axes and do the image processing and show the result image with Signal_Monitor axes]

The code like this:

```
while length>0 % length is the video duration that user set
     frame = getsnapshot(VidObj); % VidObj is the camera 
     signal = imageprocess(frame); % image processing
     axes(handles.Signal_Monitor); % show in axes Signal_Monitor
     imshow(signal); % show result image
end
```

Thanks a lot!

[image: Image show by function imshow(signal,'InitialMagnification','fit','Parent',handles.Signal_Monitor); 4x4 resolution]
Image show by function imshow(signal,'InitialMagnification','fit','Parent',handles.Signal_Monitor); 4x4 resolution

[image: mage show by function set(handles.ih, 'cData', signal); It is only a tiny region. Because I process the original image captured by camera to a very small picture. 4x4 resolution]
Image show by function set(handles.ih, 'cData', signal); It is only a tiny region. Because I process the original image captured by camera to a very small picture. 4x4 resolution

Comment: Maybe it's because of the `while`? Try to replace it with `if`. And don't use reserved words as a variable name.

Comment: Hi, Adiel. But my task is record a video and do some processing during record. So how use if to do a loop?

Comment: Ok, I don't know what else you have in the code, but how does `length` can get change, to terminate the loop?

Comment: Every second I will minus length a constant. Do you need the code? I can give you

Comment: You need to change `length` *inside* the loop.

Comment: Yes, I change length inside the loop. I use length=Total_Time-(HH*3600+MM*60+SS); where HH MM SS change every second. The programme can stop and jump out the loop.

Comment: Is this resolved then?

Comment: No, I find it must be caused by the refreshing. Because every time I click the command window. The GUI panel will popup. May be casued by the axes function in the loop or the imshow function. I don not know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of replotting the signal in every iteration, change the `CData` of your image using

```
set(ih, 'cData', signal);
```

where `ih` is the handle to the plotted image when you plot it first time using `ih = imshow(signal)`. And remove the `axes` call, when you do this you switch the focus. For example you can modify your code as follows to achieve this

```
length = Total_Time;
while length>0 % length is the video duration that user set
     frame = getsnapshot(VidObj); % VidObj is the camera 
     signal = imageprocess(frame); % image processing
     if length==Total_Time % plot only during the first iteration
         axes(handles.Signal_Monitor); % show in axes Signal_Monitor
         handles.ih = imshow(signal); % show result image
     else
         set(handles.ih, 'cData', signal);
     end
     length = Total_Time - 1;
end
```

I am sure there is a nicer way, but I don't have access to all of your code to do this.

Comment: Oh! Thanks a lot! Vahe. It works!!! I tried imshow(signal,'InitialMagnification','fit','Parent',handles.Signal_Monitor); and it also works, but when I use it the video is very laggy. This maybe because imshow function do a heavy computing? However, when I use set(handles.ih, 'cData', signal); I find the ploted image is different. imshow function will do some processing to make the image fit the axes, but set(handles.ih, 'cData', signal); will not. Do you have some solutions? Like Picture I add above

Comment: Hi, dear Vahe. Thanks very very much! I think I have sovled my problem! Thanks very much again!!!

Comment: @Lee I am glad it was helpful. Consider accepting the answer. Cheers